# After trying Ubuntu from a partitioned drive, Ubuntu keeps booting, instead of Windows

Tags: boot, windows

I've already partitioned my hard drive and I installed Linux Live usb creator on this partioned drive, which would serve as my Linux USB and of course, it went well. Restarting Windows, Ubuntu came up alright but I didn't installed it, I only used the "try ubuntu" for a while. Shutting down and restarting the computer, Windows is not loading up any longer but Ubuntu. I've also tried my "boot menu" which doesn't show linux or windows just one hard drive. Can anyone help?

I guess, the boot loader is making Ubuntu boot first, instead of showing options.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either

- Remove the USB drive.

or

- Go to the BIOS and change settings toprefer booting from hard disk over booting from USB.

Comment: My USB drive in this case is the partioned drive...and the BIOS setting is only displaying a hard drive...which will load Ubuntu instead of windows...no USB, from the boot menu

Answer (score 0):

I later discovered the cause was because my windows drive partition wasn't active, instead it was the Ubuntu partition, so I used a windows cd to make the partition active by going through the command prompt.

Then I deleted the Ubuntu partition and re-installed ubuntu through a usb into this same parition...which worked quite alright for me. I didn't have to re-install a new windows again...the command prompt "diskpart" command saved me. :)